# how to build a compiler for a dynamically typed language?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison

I have a university project in which I must build a compiler for a language chosen by the teachers using Bison and Flex in c++ .

The language is object-oriented garbage-collected dynamically-typed language .

The thing is me and my friend are just confused of how to write the mips code for `a.x` when we only know the type of a in run-time. let's see this pseudo-code :

```
class A{private x;public A(){x=10}}
class B{public x;public B(){x=2}}
class C
{
   public static main(args)
   {
      n=input('integer');
      if(n>5)
         a=new A();
      else
         a=new B();
      write(a.x);
   }
}
```

We asked the teacher, she said we store the types of the variables in the symbol table but we only give those types at run-time, that means we must build an interpreter and that what she said. but she seemed to forget that we only have the value of `n` in the mips code in some register or in the $sp(stack pointer), we don't have the value of `n` in the c++ code so we can't know the type of `a` unless there is a mips code for `tell the c++ program that the value of n is 1`.

We can make possibilities of what the type of `a` can be, in the above code `a` is either of type `A` or `B` and the mips code of `a.x` can be something like this :

```
beq type(a) A label1
li $a0,0(a)
li $v0 //code for print integer
syscall 
label1:raise exception
```

but things get complicated in this statement `a.b.c.d.etc` so this approach is horrible.

My friend asked the teacher to force the programmer to write the type so for `a.b.c` he must write `A<a>.B<b>.C<c>` for example and the result is either an exception(wrong cast or private access) or `a.b.c` but the teacher refused and I don't like it anyway.

### Methods I know

1-store the value in the symbol table : this will make generating mips useless and the program is pure c++(it's not a compiler nor an interpreter any more).

2-define a value attribute for the symbol in the symbol table but let mips code change that value, well if we said in c++ `int n` and then while generating code we say(in c++) `printf("sw $v0,0(%d)",&x)` then the mips code will really change x because it stores the value of v0 in an address which is the same as x address.

But this approach requires the assembler and the compiler to work together in parallel and parallel is just complicated for us.

So what's the best method to deal with this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you were translating your dynamic language to C++, you could lay our your language's objects like:

```
class DynamicLanguageObject
{
    int m_type;
    void* m_pValue; // stores int, double, char*, etc. depending on m_type
    map<string, DynamicLanguageObject*> m_fields;
};
```

and then the expression `a.x` in your dynamic language corresponds to `a.m_fields["x"]` in C++.  This [dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)-of-fields approach is how many dynamic languages, including JavaScript and Python, implement objects.

You “just” need to figure out how to implement a hash table in MIPS assembly language.

Comment: but what about a.f() ? I mean what about methods ? assume f exist in both A and B one private and one public